# WIN10 - LAN file sharing / User permissions

Tags: windows-10, networking, permissions, file-sharing

Noob here - I'm trying to understand how Windows 10 file sharing works in combination with user/group rights. My goal is to create a network share on my main PC that can be accessed from my laptop - but not by other machines/user accounts that are on my LAN. I'm confused about adding user privileges for the share - how is it possible that I grant access to myself (local user account on main system), but other systems (external user accounts) on the LAN can map to the drive without any obvious authentication (password)? What is the scope of share privileges/user accounts in this specific scenario?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My goal is to create a network share on my main PC that can be
> accessed from my laptop - but not by other machines/user accounts that
> are on my LAN.

Set your laptop user as a user on the Windows 10 computer that you are sharing. If you have a Microsoft Account, this step may not be needed. Make certain the users have good passwords.

**To set up a user from another computer on a machine:**

Use Manage Computer (right click Computer) and select Users and Groups. Add users here and the password the user must use. This is how I do it here.

Share the folder you wish to share to the user above and no one else. Be sure "Everyone" does not have access.

> how is it possible that I grant access to myself (local user account
> on main system), but other systems (external user accounts) on the LAN
> can map to the drive without any obvious authentication (password)?

First, make sure the Windows 10 machine that you are sharing has a strong password. No password is a security issue. Then make sure (Network and Sharing center, Advanced Settings) that password protected sharing is enforced (enable password protected sharing).

If you do this and also so long as you make sure "Everyone" is not included in Folder sharing permissions, then other users cannot get to your server.

Windows 10 is secure and you would have to permit other users as described above. Otherwise, they cannot access.

Comment: This got me on the right track, now I'm down the rabbit hole of trying to figure out how to add the laptop's user account to the Desktop's security group. Recommendations for the simplest way to do this? I am using local accounts. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I added a section in my answer to add Local Users to a machine. I do this here.

Comment: My laptop and desktop happened to have the same username/password combination, bypassing the authentication I had enabled and confusing me a bit. The way it works is crystal clear to me now - thanks again for your answer!

Comment: You are very welcome. I use Folder and File sharing here all the time and I was happy to add my knowledge   to this question.